# Nodemon - "clean exit - waiting for changes before restart" during setup

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, nodemon

I am trying to set up a RESTful API with Node and Postgres. I have run into a problem where whenever I attempt to run the server (using npm start) to test it locally, I get the following output:

> [nodemon] 1.14.10 [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs` [nodemon] watching: *.* [nodemon] starting `node index.js server.js`
>   [nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart

After searching online for quite some time, I cannot find too many resources on what exactly "clean exit - waiting for changes before restart" exactly means, especially in this case.

This is my queries.js file:

```
  1 var promise = require('bluebird');
  2 
  3 var options = {
  4   // Initialization Options
  5   promiseLib: promise
  6 };
  7 
  8 // created an instance of pg-promise, override default pgp lib w bluebird
  9 var pgp = require('pg-promise')(options);
 10 var connectionString = 'postgres://localhost:3000/actions';
 11 var db = pgp(connectionString);
 12 
 13 // add query functions
 14 
 15 module.exports = {
 16   getAllActions: getAllActions,
 17 //  getSingleAction: getSingleAction,
 18 //  createAction: createAction,
 19 //  updateAction: updateAction,
 20 //  removeAction: removeAction
 21 };
 22 
 23 function getAllActions(req, res, next) {
 24   db.any('select * from acts')
 25     .then(function (data) {
 26       res.status(200)
 27         .json({
 28           status: 'success',
 29           data: data,
 30           message: 'Retrieved ALL actions'
 31         });
 32     })
 33     .catch(function (err) {
 34       return next(err);
 35     });
 36 }
```

Here is my index.js file:

```
  3 var express = require('express');
  4 var app = express();
  5 var router = express.Router();
  6 var db = require('./queries');
  7 
  8 // structure: expressInstance.httpRequestMethod(PATH, HANDLER)
  9 app.get('/api/actions', db.getAllActions);
 10 //app.get('/api/actions/:id', db.getSingleAction);
 11 //app.post('/api/actions', db.createAction);
 12 //app.put('/api/actions/:id', db.updateAction);
 13 //app.delete('/api/actions/:id', db.removeAction);
 14 
 15 module.exports = router;
```

Any thoughts on what could be going on here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code. You never told your app to run. When you're ready creating your routes you should start your server with:

```
app.listen(<port on which the server should run here>);
```

Also you have an Express app and a router in the same file. The router should only be used as a sub module (handy when you want to divide your app over multiple files). Right now you're doing nothing with it. If you remove  the router and the export then it should work fine.

Comment: Here is a great example https://github.com/expressjs/express/tree/master/examples/route-separation

Comment: Thank you, this seemed to get rid of the problem. However, I am following [http://mherman.org/blog/2016/03/13/designing-a-restful-api-with-node-and-postgres/#.WmlSWmaZM6U](this) tutorial and got up to the point where it says to "test the request out in the browser". Notice the index.js has the express and router in the same file - in this case, is this bad practice? Or is there a misunderstanding? Just hoping for a bit of clarification here.

Comment: I've quickly looked at the tutorial but it's slightly incomplete. The app object is never created nor does it explain how to create an Express server.  I recommend you watch these tutorials instead https://m.youtube.com/watch?list=PLillGF-RfqbZMNtaOXJQiDebNXjVapWPZ&v=uONz0lEWft0 it's a mean stack tutorial but angular doesn't come to play till around part 5. The first 3-4 parts are great if you want to learn how Express works. When you're done with it you should be able to do the same with SQL.

Answer (score 2):

I am also wondering about this statement logged by nodemon. I experienced this only the last days. I get this error if some syntax error exists in my express server code. When I start the server via

```
> node server
```

the server does not start and even does not log anything to console.
Strange behaviour I think. It seems that this message has nothing to do with nodemon.
I never experienced such a thing with node in the past. Every time a syntax error was introduced I got an error message with the stack trace outputted to console.

> As I said before it was just a syntax error: A closing bracket was missing from a .then block.

After all I do not know why node was not printing the stack trace as I have experienced it before.

> I investigate further but one thing to learn from this kind of error is probably to use a linter for writing javascript code or go a step further and use TypeScript. I use TypeScript for developing the client with Angular and the possibilities to detect syntax errors early are great.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone still has issues with this how I solved mine was that I discovered my database was not connected I'm using mongodb for my setup so setting up mongo with the mongod command and running the server again with either node app.js or nodemon app.js fixed mine

Answer (score 2):

solution 1:

Firstly make sure you have included these lines of code for the Node-Express application,

```
 // 3000 is the port number in my case.
    app.listen(3000, function() {
        console.log("Server is running on port " + 3000);
    });
```

in your main file(i.e. app.js in my case) to start the server.

Solution 2:

Open your package.json file.
Check for the name of the file for the **main** field.
In my case it is
{...,"main": "**app.js**",...}.
This **app.js** is the primary entry point to the program.
Now, try to start your server with the following command,

```
nodemon app.js
```

or

```
node app.js
```

Solution 3:

If your program is running  with,

```
node app.js
```

but, not with

```
nodemon app.js
```

Then, this **problem is with** **nodemon**.
If you have **files with names** as **index.js** and **app.js** in your project, then deleting **index.js** will resolve the issue.

If index.js is the entry point to your program, then try Solution 2 given above and change the **main** field value in the **package.json** file to **index.js**
i.e.  {...,"main": "**index.js**",...}.
This will fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue after returning to one Node app (main file: app.js) after working on another Node app (main file: index.js).

If I entered

```
Nodemon app
```

I got a message like

```
[nodemon] starting `node app index.js`
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

I played around with the version of Nodemon (update made no difference), I then tried entering

```
Node app
```

and got the usual proper working response, i.e.

```
[nodemon] 1.19.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
HTTP server started at port 3000 ...
```

and I also got it going correctly when I entered

```
Nodemon app.js
```

Now, normally up to then it made no difference whether you enter **app.js** or **app** - but here ***it does*** seem to make a difference. Maybe some of the cached settings for the other Node app (i.e. the one using index.js as a main script and using **app** as an object within that file) were being retained and referenced to somehow.

Are there any Nodemon proficient people here to explain this ?

Answer (score 1):

I too had face the same issue.

Node version was 14.15.5.

so installed node 12.22 version and working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but my problem was very simple newbie issue-adding it here in case those new to express and this type of code make the same mistake

I had unknowingly included the 'app.listen' within my 'app.get' code (yes I know, very basic mistake but it was frustrating, hence giving my option here)

Wrong way

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.query);
*....additional code here...*
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("hey app is listening");
});
```

});

Right way-

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.query);
});
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("hey app is listening");
});
```

Comment: i forgot to app.listen. ty for your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
   app.listen(5010,function(){
      console.log("server is running on port 5010");
   });
```

// add the code above to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

and your program will show the error on browser refused to connect than try this code on terminal if you using express generator

> npm start
> or
> nodemon start

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of looking for a solution why my production node-build in docker always immediately stops with exit 0 I found out that the node-version of the docker-images is incompatible. If you face this problem in docker try out different node-versions

Answer (score 0):

[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
URI malformed
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart

I was able to fix this by changing the '@' symbol in my password for the connection url to %40

Answer (score 0):

Facing same problem, I just deleted the node_modules folder and package-lock.json file and reinstalled the dependencies and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is 2022, so if anyone still has this error, here's a fix that worked for me.
Make sure that your "start" command in "scripts" package.json is pointing to your entry file for the application.

```
`
 "scripts": {

 "dev": "nodemon src/server.ts",

 "start": "nodemon dist/server.js",

 "postinstall": "tsc"
}

`
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you invoke start? For me that was a problem in app.js.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem some days back, I find no error in the code here. You only have to run the code in the folder where you have installed the nodemon.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart ?

Ans: Check your internet connection,
When restart my app my connection is lost thats why it will give the this err...